# Validator error with doctype html 4

Tags: html

I'm getting the following [errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services) in the validator which don't make sense:

> Line 24, Column 83: document type does not allow element "LINK" here
>   …nk href="/js/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"
>   type="text/css" />
>
> Line 11, Column 73: NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES

Head code:

```
 <head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="k2swFjvEvzvhvlNU_8Yy1D_35wKjBfT3Q8zb3kHFOqo">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="Description" content="" />
    <meta name="y_key" content="96d6af6a44f807e8" />
    <!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/HeadCSS.asp"-->

    <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="/js/pikame/styles/bottom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pikame/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pikame/lib/jquery.pikachoose.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document.body).click(function () {
          $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
        });

      });
      </script>
    </head>
```

The Doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: try use doctype <!doctype html>

Comment: I think the line numbers are wrong, please give full HTML and I could try to find what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using XHTML `/>` syntax in an HTML 4 document, which doesn't work as you expect because `/>` has a special meaning in HTML 4. Empty element tags should simply end in `>` in HTML 4. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5/3558200#3558200) for details.

Unless you have a very good reason to use an HTML 4 doctype, though, the simplest solution is to just swap it out for the HTML5 doctype which allow `/>` syntax precisely for situations like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```